# Is it possible to have default filter values in Apache Solr?

Tags: solr

Is it possible to tell Solr to use a specific filter value if no other filter is defined for that field?

Example:
If there is no other `fq` entry present for a field *age* then search by default for *age* > 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can [add these to the requestHandler definition](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/RequestHandlers+and+SearchComponents+in+SolrConfig#RequestHandlersandSearchComponentsinSolrConfig-SearchHandlers):

```
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="fq">age:[18 TO *]</str>
</lst>
```

(or if you really meant larger than 18 and not 18 or older, `{18 TO *]` or `[19 TO *]`).

You can also use `appends` and `invariants` instead of defaults to add a filter query to all queries or set a parameter to a static value that an URL parameter can't override.

Comment: The problem is that I might have other `fq` entries defined but no filter for `age`. In this case, the `fq` default with the `age` filter will have to effect, since it is overridden by the other filters.

Comment: If you need more advanced logic then I think you're going to have to do this in your middleware, since there is no way to read and analyze a parameter to know that its just filtering by a single field in Solr from the configuration. You can extend the requestHandler and write your own java code though..

Comment: You are definitely right. I ended up with a simpler solution by using two different request handler: one with appender and the other one without. Thank you for your help!